# php require and autoload

Tags: php, require, autoload

I use __autoload to load classes, and I keep getting errors that no class is found but file get's loaded ok.
Then if I change something in a file, just something like add a new line and save it, everything works fine and class is then found. 
But this is a great problem cause there are thousands of files in this project and I don't want to change them one by one. 
I'm using php 5.3.0 on windows.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you use some extension to cache PHP scripts like php accelerators?

Comment: Yes php_apc.dll, Alternative PHP Cache

Comment: As I see it, it seems to be a bug in php 5.3 http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=14066

Comment: Try to delete the APC cache every time you edit a file

Comment: But that isn't a problem, I don't want to edit a file, project has been exported from SVN, there are a lot of files there and they should work out of the box. When I edit a file, then everything works. It's a weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is only with php version 5.3.0 and corresponding php_apc.dll